# Error found when using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, ios4, asihttprequest

I am trying to use the ASIHTTPrequest. but i get the below error message when i run my code.

Anything wrong in my code please help me up and thanks

> Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=6 "Unable to obtain information
>   on proxy servers needed for request" UserInfo=0x6043490
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to obtain information on proxy servers
>   needed for request}

Below is my source code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];

  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [request setDelegate:self];

  [request startSynchronous];   

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
  NSLog(@"Error %@", [request error]);

  if ([request error])
  {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Fail." 
                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

    [alert release];

     return;
  }
```

}

Comment: It's not specific to your problem and might not actually solve it, but you should put `[super viewDidLoad]` to the top in your `viewDidLoad`method. Did you follow the instructions on how to set this up? http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Comment: does this happen in simulator and/or device?

Comment: It seems you don't have internet connections(Open proxy) to call that site link in your code. If u have open proxy in your system safari browser then it will work in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for the error message turns up several results in the ASIHTTPRequest mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/924540472d721696/0dd6d853005631b0

http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/c15bcb756773685a

In short, it seems like there's a good chance the error is related to a problem fetching the proxy autoconfiguration file.

So:

1. Check your networking settings on the device and see if there is an incorrect or inaccessible PAC URL set
2. Try upgrading to the latest git version of ASIHTTPRequest which has some fixes in this area, and will ignore bad/unreachable PAC urls.